# Pasar variables de una clase a otra (JFrame)

Tags: java, jframe

estudio desarrollo de software  y de un semestre a otro nos cambiaron el lenguaje de programación (C# -> Java) Para adaptarnos, nos ponen programas sencillos pero tuve un problema con uno que no se como resolverlo. A veces tengo problemas al comprender clases y mi problema es que intento pasar unas variables que se calculan en la clase principal (Que se ejecuta en consola) a otra clase (que ya es un JFrame) pero la verdad no sé como (no se si fijar las variables como propiedades de la clase o instanciando la clase del jframe, la verdad no se)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Inicio declaracion de variables
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int clientes[] = new int[20];
    int op, i = 0;
    String val1="",val2="",val3="",val4="",val5="";
    //Fin declaracion de variables
    //Inicio de mensajes
    mensaje("Bienvenido a la cafeteria estudiantil!");
    mensaje("");
    mensaje("Porfavor, califique nuestro servicio con la siguiente escala");
    mensaje("");
    mensaje("");
    mensaje("--- 1. Pesimo ---");
    mensaje("--- 2. Regular ---");
    mensaje("--- 3. Bueno ---");
    mensaje("--- 4. Muy bueno ---");
    mensaje("--- 5. Excelente ---");
    mensaje("");
    //Fin de mensajes
    //Inicio de captura de datos
    do{
        String men = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cliente numero "+(i+1)+" ¿Cual es su opinion?");
        clientes[i] = Integer.parseInt(men);
        //Si el usuario pone un numero que no sea 1-5 No sumará nada el contador i ni asignará valores, solo mandara un mensaje de error
        if(clientes[i] == 1 || clientes[i] == 2 || clientes[i] == 3 || clientes[i] == 4 || clientes[i] == 5){
            op = clientes[i];
            i++;
            switch(op){
                case 1:
                    val1+="*";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    val2+="*";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    val3+="*";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    val4+="*";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    val5+="*";
                    break;
            }
        } else { //Este es el mensaje de error que va a mandar
            mensaje("");
            mensaje("Porfavor, introduzca una opcion valida e intentelo de nuevo");
            mensaje("");
        }
    } while(i < clientes.length); //Se repite el bucle hasta que pasen los 20 alumnos
    //Mensajes con los resultados finales
    mensaje("");
    mensaje("Estos son los resultados de la encuesta:");
    mensaje("");
    mensaje("");
    mensaje("--- 1. Pesimo --- |" + val1+"|");
    mensaje("--- 2. Regular --- |" + val2+"|");
    mensaje("--- 3. Bueno --- |" + val3+"|");
    mensaje("--- 4. Muy bueno --- |" + val4+"|");
    mensaje("--- 5. Excelente --- |" + val5+"|");
    mensaje("");
    mensaje("En total se entrevistó a "+ clientes.length + " estudiantes");
    Salida sal = new Salida();
    sal.setTitle("RESULTADO");
    sal.show();

}

static void mensaje(String mens){ //Metodo para evitar escribir todo el choro de System.out.println sustituyendolo por mensaje("mensaje");
    System.out.println(mens);
}
```

}`

Y la clase del JFrame es esta

```
public class Salida extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Salida
 */
public Salida() {
    initComponents();

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    lblTexto1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblTexto2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblTexto3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblTexto4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblTexto5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblTexto6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblPesimo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblRegular = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblBueno = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblMuyBueno = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblExcelente = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    lblTexto1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblTexto1.setText("2. Regular");

    lblTexto2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblTexto2.setText("1. Pesimo");

    lblTexto3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblTexto3.setText("3. Bueno");

    lblTexto4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblTexto4.setText("4. Muy bueno");

    lblTexto5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblTexto5.setText("5. Excelente");

    lblTexto6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
    lblTexto6.setText("Valoracion final");

    lblPesimo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblPesimo.setText("||");

    lblRegular.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblRegular.setText("||");

    lblBueno.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblBueno.setText("||");

    lblMuyBueno.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblMuyBueno.setText("||");

    lblExcelente.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblExcelente.setText("||");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(148, 148, 148)
                    .addComponent(lblTexto6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 320, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lblTexto2)
                        .addComponent(lblTexto1)
                        .addComponent(lblTexto3)
                        .addComponent(lblTexto4)
                        .addComponent(lblTexto5))
                    .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lblExcelente)
                        .addComponent(lblMuyBueno)
                        .addComponent(lblBueno)
                        .addComponent(lblRegular)
                        .addComponent(lblPesimo))))
            .addContainerGap(153, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(lblTexto6)
            .addGap(62, 62, 62)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblTexto2)
                .addComponent(lblPesimo))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblTexto1)
                .addComponent(lblRegular))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblTexto3)
                .addComponent(lblBueno))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblTexto4)
                .addComponent(lblMuyBueno))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblTexto5)
                .addComponent(lblExcelente))
            .addContainerGap(74, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Salida.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Salida.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Salida.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Salida.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>


    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Salida().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel lblBueno;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblExcelente;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblMuyBueno;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblPesimo;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblRegular;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblTexto1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblTexto2;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblTexto3;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblTexto4;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblTexto5;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblTexto6;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar datos de entre Jframe necesitas tener la variable de tipo publico estatico; en en este ejemplo es Jlabel

```
public static final JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
```

Lo siguiente tienes que hacer es llamar al metodo del jlabel1 para colocar los datos que quieres enviar en este caso j1 que es el frame.

```
Jframe1 j1 = new Jframe1();
j1.jLabel1.setText("dato a pasar");
```

Espero te sirva de algo este aporte!